# ESET NOD32 4.0 - Lost settings password

Tags: nod32, password-recovery

A friend of mine forgot his NOD32 4.0 security password, so now he can't change the Antivirus settings and it keeps reporting a false positive. The worst part is he can't even uninstall it!

Is there a way to reset / recover the password or do I have to reinstall the operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try NOD's [unlock utility](http://www.eset.eu/knowledge-base/settings-are-password-protected)

> ESET has created an Unlock Utility to remove the administrative password and restore your > access to the configuration settings. Please follow the instructions below to use the > ESET Unlock Utility:
>
> - Save the program [unlockv3.exe](http://download.eset.com/unlockv3.exe) to your local harddisk.
> - Run program unlockv3.exe (double-click on the file icon) – a new window displays on the desktop.
> - Send us the ID number that displays via e-mail to support@eset.eu together with your username and password that was sent to you after the purchase (for verification). If you don’t know your username and password, it is possible to have them sent. [(More detailed info here](http://www.eset.eu/support/forgot-password-for-updates) ).
> - Close the window by clicking on the Quit button.
> - Wait for your UNLOCK CODE - it will be sent back to your e-mail address.
>     When you receive the e-mail with your UNLOCK CODE, run unlockv3.exe again. (in Windows Vista, please make sure you run it under an administrator account).
> - Insert the UNLOCK CODE into the "UNLOCK CODE" dialog box (please enter the code correctly).
> - Click on the "Unlock" button.
> - Click on the Quit button.

Answer (score 1):

If you have physical access to the client you have 3 Options:

1. Hack it.

   - Reboot into safe-mode. (only needed if NOD32 is in self-protection mode).
   - Remove the following registry key:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Eset\Nod\CurrentVersion\Info\PackageID

   - Reboot
2. Use official tools (uninstall) (similar to ***Sathya*** suggestion)
   This article describes how to uninstall ESET NOD32 without supplying the password, using “ESETUninstaller”.
   This solution requires a third-party program (from ESET).

   http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2289
3. Contact Customer Support

   http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN333

Source:

http://heineborn.com/tech/resetting-or-clearing-nod32-client-password/